# Issue Installing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, homestead

I'm trying to install Laravel for the first time but every time I run this line:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel first
```

I get this error in the following picture:

[image: screenshot of error]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use another example from official documentation:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"
```

Comment: but you should change the version to `5.2.*` if you want the newest Laravel. At least he was trying to install 5.2

Comment: @Peh, I've just posted example from installation manual. OP has tried command from 5.2 installation manual and it didn't work, so I've posted example from 5.1 manual.